# Which country does the datacenter sit for East Asia and SouthEast Asia

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

Can someone provide information which geographical location does "East Asia" and "SouthEast Asia" Azure Data center sit?

Comment: Have you tried Googling "azure data centers locations"? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/global-infrastructure/locations/

Comment: @kumar Take a look. You could check as a whole [Azure regions map](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure data center `East Asia`  located in `Hong Kong` and `Southeast Asia`  located `Singapore`

You can found all the azure data center list [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/locations/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above. There are details on data centers on the [Azure Data Center list](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/locations/).

As you tagged Microsoft Graph. You will also want to see what is available in [each data center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments).